[ANSIBLE][FORTIGATE] Error in repo for the module fortios_log_webtrends_filter
I am having trouble using ansible to push playbook on fortigate.
In fact, I am writing a playbook to filter urls through categories. To do that i use the module fortinet.fortios.fortios_lo_webtrends_filter.
This is my playbook :
 - hosts: all
  collections:
    - fortinet.fortios
  connection: httpapi

  vars:
    vdom: "root"
    ansible_httpapi_use_ssl: yes
    ansible_httpapi_validate_certs: no
    ansible_httpapi_port: 11443
    category_to_filter:
      - "pornography"
      - "malware"
      - "spyware"
      - "phishing"
      - "drug"
      - "jeuxvidéos"
      - "hack"

  tasks:
  - name: Filtrer les urls par catégories
    fortinet.fortios.fortios_log_webtrends_filter:
      vdom:  "{{ vdom }}"
      log_webtrends_filter:
        anomaly: "enable"
        dns: "enable"
        filter: "{{ item }}"
        filter_type: "include"
    loop: "{{ category_to_filter }}"

My issue is that every time i receive the same error which is :
failed:
failed: [fortigate01] (item=pornography) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "pornography", "meta": {"build": 528, "http_method": "POST", "http_status": 405, "name": "filter", "path": "log.webtrends", "serial": "FG200D3913802665", "status": "error", "vdom": "root", "version": "v6.0.17"}, "msg": "Error in repo"}
failed: [fortigate01] (item=malware) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "malware", "meta": {"build": 528, "http_method": "POST", "http_status": 405, "name": "filter", "path": "log.webtrends", "serial": "FG200D3913802665", "status": "error", "vdom": "root", "version": "v6.0.17"}, "msg": "Error in repo"}
failed: [fortigate01] (item=spyware) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "spyware", "meta": {"build": 528, "http_method": "POST", "http_status": 405, "name": "filter", "path": "log.webtrends", "serial": "FG200D3913802665", "status": "error", "vdom": "root", "version": "v6.0.17"}, "msg": "Error in repo"}
failed: [fortigate01] (item=phishing) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "phishing", "meta": {"build": 528, "http_method": "POST", "http_status": 405, "name": "filter", "path": "log.webtrends", "serial": "FG200D3913802665", "status": "error", "vdom": "root", "version": "v6.0.17"}, "msg": "Error in repo"}
failed: [fortigate01] (item=drug) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "drug", "meta": {"build": 528, "http_method": "POST", "http_status": 405, "name": "filter", "path": "log.webtrends", "serial": "FG200D3913802665", "status": "error", "vdom": "root", "version": "v6.0.17"}, "msg": "Error in repo"}
failed: [fortigate01] (item=jeux-vidéos) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "jeux-vidéos", "meta": {"build": 528, "http_method": "POST", "http_status": 405, "name": "filter", "path": "log.webtrends", "serial": "FG200D3913802665", "status": "error", "vdom": "root", "version": "v6.0.17"}, "msg": "Error in repo"}
failed: [fortigate01] (item=hack) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "hack", "meta": {"build": 528, "http_method": "POST", "http_status": 405, "name": "filter", "path": "log.webtrends", "serial": "FG200D3913802665", "status": "error", "vdom": "root", "version": "v6.0.17"}, "msg": "Error in repo"}

I am using a fortigate 200D and the firmware version is v6.0.17 build0528 (GA) and the machine that uses ansible is an ubuntu 22.04 and the ansible version is 2.16.6
and here the verbose output :
<192.168.1.99> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /home/user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-1566cleiru3m `"&& mkdir "` echo /home/user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-1566cleiru3m/ansible-tmp-1715757566.7115493-1647-45405879679674 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1715757566.7115493-1647-45405879679674="` echo /home/user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-1566cleiru3m/ansible-tmp-1715757566.7115493-1647-45405879679674 `" ) && sleep 0'
Using module file /home/user/.ansible/collections/ansible_collections/fortinet/fortios/plugins/modules/fortios_log_webtrends_filter.py
<192.168.1.99> PUT /home/user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-1566cleiru3m/tmp1a0p1nif TO /home/user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-1566cleiru3m/ansible-tmp-1715757566.7115493-1647-45405879679674/AnsiballZ_fortios_log_webtrends_filter.py
<192.168.1.99> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'chmod u+x /home/user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-1566cleiru3m/ansible-tmp-1715757566.7115493-1647-45405879679674/ /home/user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-1566cleiru3m/ansible-tmp-1715757566.7115493-1647-45405879679674/AnsiballZ_fortios_log_webtrends_filter.py && sleep 0'
<192.168.1.99> EXEC /bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/python3 /home/user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-1566cleiru3m/ansible-tmp-1715757566.7115493-1647-45405879679674/AnsiballZ_fortios_log_webtrends_filter.py && sleep 0'
<192.168.1.99> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /home/user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-1566cleiru3m/ansible-tmp-1715757566.7115493-1647-45405879679674/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
failed: [fortigate01] (item=hack) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "access_token": null,
            "log_webtrends_filter": {
                "anomaly": "enable",
                "dns": "enable",
                "filter": "hack",
                "filter_type": "include",
                "forward_traffic": null,
                "gtp": null,
                "local_traffic": null,
                "multicast_traffic": null,
                "netscan_discovery": null,
                "netscan_vulnerability": null,
                "severity": null,
                "sniffer_traffic": null,
                "ssh": null,
                "voip": null
            },
            "vdom": "root"
        }
    },
    "item": "hack",
    "meta": {
        "build": 528,
        "http_method": "POST",
        "http_status": 405,
        "name": "filter",
        "path": "log.webtrends",
        "serial": "FG200D3913802665",
        "status": "error",
        "vdom": "root",
        "version": "v6.0.17"
    },
    "msg": "Error in repo"
}

If someone can help me i'd be really gratefull. Thank you

Run the playbook with -vvvv and add the output to the question.

hi Thank you Mircea, i have edited my post where you can find the verbose output :)
